predict by Using geographically weighted logistic regression in R
I used GWmodel package to do GWLR now I want to predict data values ​​but for family="binomial" I can't find its function while for logit function I want this prediction on 30% from the model points. Is there a library in r that can do this. Otherwise, is it possible to write a prediction function for the 30% of the data points that did not participate in the GWLR modeling? (70% of data have participated in forming the model and the number of observations is 1000 observations)
library(GWmodel)
GWLR_data.shp <- st_read(paste0(a,d))
shapefile_sp <- as(GWLR_data.shp, "Spatial")
waterway <- (shapefile_sp$water)/1000#Dis_Waterw
qanat <- (shapefile_sp$qanat)/1000#Dis_Qanat
road <- (shapefile_sp$road)/1000#Dis_Road
slope <- shapefile_sp$slope#ValueSlope
TRI <- shapefile_sp$TRI#Value_TRI
X <- cbind(waterway,qanat,road,slope,TRI)
Y<-shapefile_sp$historical
formula<-Y ~X
DM <- gw.dist(dp.locat = coordinates(shapefile_sp)) #creat distance matrix for w
bw <- bw.ggwr(formula,data=shapefile_sp, dMat=DM,family ="binomial",
approach="AICc",kernel="bisquare",adaptive=TRUE)
GWLR<-ggwr.basic(formula, bw=bw,data=shapefile_sp, dMat=DM,family ="binomial",kernel = "bisquare",adaptive = TRUE)

